# x264 [error]: main profile doesn't support 4:4:4

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing videos using HTML5 Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856643/playing-videos-using-html5-tag)

I have an open question here, [Playing videos using HTML5 Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856643/playing-videos-using-html5-tag).

I am getting the above mentioned error when I try the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i file.mov -s 320x240 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 2 -r 15 -ab 44100 -aspect 16:9 OUTPUT_VIDEO.mp4
```

Hope someone can help me. I am trying to output for android and iOS.

Comment: It may be a colorspace problem, check if this works :`-vf "format=yuv420p"`

Comment: Thanks @arashkordi! It converts. Sadly, the video is still not outputing on android.